# How do I respawn threads if they die

Tags: java, multithreading

I have multiple threads of multiple types (Different classes). I want in case one of them throws an exception and dies to be replaced by another NEW thread. I am aware of the join thread function but how would I go about implementing them for 5 different type of threads such as in case type 1 thread dies is instantly replaced without having to wait for type 2 to die first.

This is some sample pseudo-code.

```
class1 implements runnable{
  void run(){
     try{
       while(true){
         repeat task
        }
     } catch(Exception e){
      log error
     }
  }
}


class2 implements runnable{
  void run(){
     try{
       while(true){
         repeat task
        }
     } catch(Exception e){
      log error
     }
  }
}


class3 implements runnable{
  void run(){
     try{
       while(true){
         repeat task
        }
     } catch(Exception e){
      log error
     }
  }
}

public main(){

 // start all threads .start()
}
```

Comment: Don't subclass Thread, implement Runnables and execute them using an Executor (see Executors).

Comment: @isnot2bad, I am having hard time to understand what you mean. Can u show me an example?

Comment: Can you add some code so that we know what the threads are doing in their run method? Why can they 'die', and what should happen when they have died.

Comment: @isnot2bad I made an edit. Please check it out.

Comment: In this day and age managing your own Threads is working too hard.  Take a look at http://akka.io/ or something.  Let a framework do the Thread management and concentrate on your tasks.

Comment: @user2789433 OK, got that. But what do you want to do when an exception causes a Runnable to terminate?

Comment: just re spawn the same thread with another .start() or similar function.

Comment: When you don't want the thread to die, you should catch the exception within the while loop instead.

Comment: @isnot2bad the problem is that I don't know what type of exception it is and how I would recover from it.

Comment: But then, starting a new Thread won't help either. Using threads won't make a program more correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want in case one of them throws an exception and dies to be replaced by another NEW thread.

I don't quite understand why you can't do:

```
public void run() {
   // only quit the loop if the thread is interrupted
   while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
      try {
         // do some stuff that might throw
         repeat task;
      } catch (Exception e) {
         // recover from the throw here but then continue running
      }
   }
}
```

Why do you need to restart a NEW thread?  Just because a task threw an exception doesn't mean that it is somehow corrupt and it needs a fresh one to work appropriately.  If you are trying to catch *all* exceptions (including `RuntimeException`) then `catch (Exception e)` will do this.  If you want to be *really* careful you can even catch `Throwable` in case there is a chance that `Error`s are being generated – this is relatively rare.

If you actually have multiple tasks (or really anytime you are dealing with threads), you should consider using the `ExecutorService` classes.  See the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html).

```
// create a thread pool with 10 workers
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
// or you can create an open-ended thread pool
// ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
// define your jobs somehow
threadPool.submit(new Class1());
threadPool.submit(new Class2());
...
// once we have submitted all jobs to the thread pool, it should be shutdown
threadPool.shutdown();
```

So instead of forking a thread to do multiple tasks, you start a thread pool and it starts threads as necessary to accomplish a bunch of tasks.  If a task fails, you could certain submit another task to the pool although that's a slightly strange pattern.

If you want to wait for all of the tasks to finish you'd use:

```
threadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: This 'restart thread' is a recurring theme.  I wonder what book/site has never heard of a loop?  Such resources need exterminating before any more devs. get infected.

Comment: No idea @MartinJames.  Maybe a holdover from C where the memory might be in some unstable state or something?

Answer (score 1):

```
      boolean shouldStop() {
        // it's a good idea to think about how/when to stop ;)
        return false;
      }
      void runThreadGivenType(final Runnable taskToRun) {
        new Thread() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            try {
              taskToRun.run();
            } finally {
              if (!shouldStop()) {
                runThreadGivenType(taskToRun);
              }
            }
          }
        }.start();
      }

      public void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        runThreadGivenType(new Runnable() { public void run() { System.out.println("I'm almost immortal thread!"); throw new RuntimeException(); } });
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
      }
```

and it's a good idea to think about executors to manage thread pools too. plain, [un/hand]-managed threads are not the best practice ;)